# Importing functions from module with dependencies without raising ImportErrors

Tags: python, exception, python-import

I have a package called `analysis`.

When I import this package (with the command `from app import analysis`) I get an `ImportError` exception because of a missing library that should be imported in another package (`web_package`).

I want to be able to import `analysis` even if I do not have that library installed, because `analysis` is only importing functions from `web_package` that can work even without the library.

**analysis/__init__.py**:

```
from app.analysis.util import some_function
```

**analysis/util.py** :

```
from app.web_package.util import some_other_function
```

**web_package/__init__.py** :

```
from app.web_package.web_client import SomeClass
```

**web_package/web_client.py** :

```
from missing_library import ParentClass

def SomeClass(ParentClass):
```

At this point what can I do if I do not have `missing_library` installed, but I still want to use some functions from `web_package/util.py`? Whenever I try to import something from `app.web_package.util` it automatically goes into `web_package/__init__.py` and then in `web_client.py`, that causes an `ImportError` to be raised. What can I do?

Wrapping `from missing_library import ParentClass` into a `try/except` block will cause an error with `def SomeClass(ParentClass)`.

Answer (score 1):

I would say the easiest way to go would be to refactor your code into two different modules.

One module has the `missing_library` import and only has code that depends on this `missing_library` like  `SomeClass` , then the other module has the functions, that you want to use, that are not dependent on the missing library.

Then if you want to use some of those independent functions in your dependent module, you can simply import that module in it.

Then in your `__init__.py` , you can put the `try/except` Example -

```
try:
    from app.web_package.web_client import SomeClass
except ImportError:
    pass                                #Or import some other version of `SomeClass` ?
```

Comment: Thank you. I think this could be the easiest way to fix the problem. However, I was hoping for something that would not change the package structure. If you also have other options I would be grateful to read about them.

Answer (score 1):

You could define a stub in an except clause. The following works:

```
try:
   from foo import bar;
except:
   class foo:
      pass

class baz(foo):
   pass
```

It is pretty bad design, though, imho, but that's fairly opinionated.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you please provide information about why this might be considered bad design, and why it is opinionated?

Comment: You won't be able to predict the behavior of the module if you hide errors like these, which I would consider an instability. In other words, not knowing the internals could change your app's behavior entirely when the module becomes available for some reason.